# Why does GCC warn against this implicit conversion?

Tags: c, gcc, type-conversion, compiler-warnings

GCC warns me that the following piece of code contains an implicit conversion that may change a value:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
float square = rand();
```

However, the following does not yield any warning:

```
float square = 100;
```

The warning given by GCC is a follows:

```
tests/ChemTests.cpp:17:23: error: conversion to ‘float’ from ‘int’ may alter its value
```

I don't understand why the former would give a warning, since `rand()` is properly declared and returns an `int`, just as the `100` integer literal.

**Why does the first line give a compiler warning but not the second, even though both have an implicit conversion from `int`to `float`?**

Comment: I find that I don't get the warning unless I use the `-Wconversion` option.

Answer (score 15):

GCC emits this warning when a loss of precision may result from the cast. (in other words, the value may be "altered")

In the first case, `rand()` returns an `int`. Since not all values that can be stored in an `int` are representable as a `float`, it will emit this warning.

In the second case, 100 can be safely casted to a `float` without any precision loss.

Comment: Does this mean that `float f = 123456789` will give an error?

Comment: It won't error, but it should give a warning. I don't have GCC in front of me this moment, but I just tested it in Visual Studio and it gives a warning: `warning C4305: 'initializing' : truncation from 'int' to 'float'`

Answer (score 6):

To add something to what Mysticial wrote (that is correct): your implementation of C uses `float` that are [32 bits IEEE 754 single precision binary floating-point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format) and `int` that are 32 bits. In "your" `int` you can have 31 bits of number and 1 bit of sign. In "your" float the `mantissa` is 24 bits and there is 1 bit of sign. Clearly `int`s that need more than 24 bits plus sign to be represented can't be converted exactly to "your" `float`. (I use the "your" to represent "your" compiler, the compiler you are using. The C standard doesn't tell the exact length of `float` or `int`).

Now, the `rand()` can generate any `int` number, so the compiler has to give you the warning. The `100` is a numeric literal that is known at compile time, so the compiler can statically check if that number is convertible.

(even without explaining exactly how floating points work, your `int` is 32 bits and "supports" only integer numbers. Your `float` is 32 bits and "supports" floating point numbers. Clearly floating point numbers are more difficult to represent (you have to save somewhere where the decimal point is), so there must be a "price" you pay if both `int` and `float` have the same length. The price is precision.)

To respond to the comment you made, the maximum number you can represent exactly in a `float` that is "contiguous" to 0 (so that 0...number are all exactly representable) are 16777215 (that has mantissa = 16777215 and exponent = 0) and 16777216 (that has mantissa = 1 and exponent = 24, because it's 1 * 2 ^ 24). 16777217 isn't representable exactly. 16777218 is.

Answer (score 0):

Not every `int` can be represented as a `float`. Specifically, if the number of bits between the highest and lowest bit set in an `int` is greater than `FLT_MANT_DIG - 1`, defined in `<float.h>`, it cannot be represented precisely as a `float`. (Same goes for `double` and `DBL_MANT_DIG - 1`.) The compiler warns you that there's a potential loss of precision because the declaration of `rand()` means that `rand()` could return any `int`, including those that cannot be represented as a `float`.

gcc should be smart enough to know when `int` literals can be represented precisely:

```
float f= 1<<FLT_MANT_DIG; // yes
float g= (1<<FLT_MANT_DIG) - 1; // yes
float h= (1<<FLT_MANT_DIG) + 1; // no
float i= (1<<(FLT_MANT_DIG + 1)); // yes
```

gcc should spit out a warning for initializing `h` only.

Incidentally, if `RAND_MAX` is less than or equal to `(1<<FLT_MANT_DIG) - 1`, you can safely assign `rand()` to a `float`, even if the compiler complains to you.